# In proving an irreducible curve has only finitely many singular points, is $f_x \not \equiv 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves

Artin Algebra Chapter 11

[image]

This has been answered on the site, but I want to ask about the solution given by [Brian Bi](http://brianbi.ca/artin/11.9):

> The constant polynomials are not considered irreducible, so f is not constant. Therefore ∂f/∂x or ∂f/∂y is nonzero (possibly both). Applying Theorem 11.9.10 to f and one of its nonzero partial derivatives yields the desired result.

My question is about

> Therefore ∂f/∂x or ∂f/∂y is nonzero (possibly both).

**In Chapter 11.9, we have a definition of irreducible** for a complex polynomial of two variables that is part of a sentence, but I'm not sure if the last part is part of the sentence is part of the definition.

> Let's assume that the polynomial f is irreducible - that it is not a product of two nonconstant polynomials, and also that it has positive degree in the variable x.

Here is the context:

[image]

[image]

Now:

- **If positive degree in x is part** of the definition of irreducible and if $f$ has positive degree in $x$, then it's definitely the case that ∂f/∂x is nonzero while ∂f/∂y is the one that we are not sure is nonzero right?
- **If positive degree in x is not part** of the definition of irreducible, then how do we say constants are irreducible? In Chapter 11.8, this is explicit.

For reference, the **definition of an irreducible polynomial in one variable in the previous section Chapter 11.8 is**:

> A polynomial with coefficients in a field is called irreducible if it is not constant and if is not the product of two polynomials, neither of which is a constant.

Here is the context:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "how do we say constants are irreducible?"?  Constants are not irreducible, as stated explicitly in the definition of irreducible.

Comment: @EricWofsey In Chapter 11.8 it is explicit. In Chapter 11.9, it is not explicit. I edited to clarify.

Comment: The statement in 11.9 is not a definition and is not meant to be read as one (the definition was already given in 11.8!).  It's just a brief reminder to the reader of what "irreducible" means, which slightly sloppily omits the condition that $f$ is nonconstant, but that doesn't really matter because of the additional assumption that the degree in $x$ is positive.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you, so add that to answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're parsing the last quote wrong.  It should be read as

> Let's assume [that the polynomial f is irreducible - that it is not a product of two nonconstant polynomials], and also that it has positive degree in the variable x.

In other words, the condition that $f$ has positive degree in $x$ is *not* part of the definition of "irreducible", but is instead an additional assumption being made in addition to $f$ being irreducible.  To be clear, the precise definition of what it means for $f$ to be irreducible is that $f$ is nonconstant and cannot be written as a product of two nonconstant polynomials.  This sentence is in no way intended as a redefinition of the term "irreducible"; it just contains a brief reminder for the reader of what it means (which omits the nonconstant condition).

In any case, in problem 9.9, there is no assumption that $f$ has positive degree in $x$.  You are right that if we knew it had positive degree in $x$, then $\partial f/\partial x$ would be nonzero.

(Incidentally, Brian Bi's solution is incomplete.  Theorem 11.9.10 only applies to polynomials with no nonconstant common factor, and so some argument must be given that $f$ and its nonzero partial derivative satisfy this condition.  Here you must use the fact that $f$ is irreducible, not just nonconstant.)

Comment: I thought that too, but what about the previous section where the definition of irreducible is "A polynomial with coefficients in a field is called irreducible if it is not constant and if is not the product of two polynomials, neither of which is a constant." ? My thought was that the positive degree in $x$ is part of irreducible and so $f$ is still not constant. In this section, how do we say constants are not irreducible? Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask.  Another possibility that just occurred to me is that the quote is from a context where $x$ is the _only_ variable, so $f$ having positive degree in $x$ is just another way of saying that $f$ is nonconstant.  It's really quite difficult to understand the quotes you are referring to when you do not provide more context.

Comment: Eric Wofsey, I added the context and made some edits to clarify