# Definition of Degree of Polynomials in several variables. (H2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 24, H2.

> Let $A$ be an integral domain, and $A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ denote the ring of the polynomial in $n$ letters $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ with coefficients in $A$.
>
> Give a reasonable definition of the *degree* of any polynomial $p(x,y)$ in $A[x,y]$ and
>   then list all the polynomials of degree $\le 3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x,y]$.

<strike>First Attempt (failed):</strike>

Define

$\qquad\require{cancel}\cancel{\operatorname{deg} p(x,y) = \operatorname{deg} p_y(x) + \operatorname{deg} p_x(y)}$

where $\operatorname{deg} p_y(x)$ denotes the degree of $x$ in $p(x,y)$, and $\operatorname{deg} p_x(y)$ the degree of $y$ in $p(x,y)$.

Second Attempt:

Let

$\quad\displaystyle p(x,y) = \sum_{0\le k\le n, i+j=k} a_{(i,j)}x^iy^j$

where $a_{(i,j)}$ are the coefficients in $A$, and $n$ is the largest (but not necessarily unique) integer such that $i+j=n$ and $a_{(i,j)}\ne 0$.  We can then define

$\quad\operatorname{deg} p(x,y)=n$.

To list all the polynomials of degree $\le 3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x,y]$,
let $i, j$ and $a_{(i,j)} \in \mathbb{Z}_3$.

- $p(x,y)$ of degree $0$: $a_{(0,0)}$.
- $p(x,y)$ of degree $1$: $a_{(0,0)} + a_{(1,0)}x + a_{(0,1)}y$,
  where either $a_{(1,0)}$ or $a_{(0,1)}$ is not zero.
- $p(x,y)$ of degree $2$: $a_{(0,0)} + a_{(1,0)}x + a_{(0,1)}y + a_{(2,0)}x^2 + a_{(1,1)}xy + a_{(0,2)}y^2$,
  where not all $a_{(2,0)}, a_{(1,1)}$ and $a_{(0,2)}$ are zeros.
- $p(x,y)$ of degree $3$: 
  $a_{(0,0)} + a_{(1,0)}x + a_{(0,1)}y + a_{(2,0)}x^2 + a_{(1,1)}xy + a_{(0,2)}y^2 + a_{(3,0)}x^3 + a_{(2,1)}x^2y + a_{(1,2)}xy^2  + a_{(0,3)}y^3$

$\qquad$where not all $a_{(3,0)}, a_{(2,1)}, a_{(1,2)}$ and $a_{(0,3)}$ are zeros.

Is this reasonable?

Comment: You can compare your attempt with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056563/whats-the-degree-of-a-multivariate-polynomial-in-artin-algebra). There the highest degree of its monomials is considered. This is also a "reasonable definition of the degree".

Answer (score 1):

The polynomials you give don't fit the definition, as for example the polynomial $x^2+y^2$ has degree $2$ both in $x$ and in $y$, so it has the degree $4$ with your definition. Yet you listed it in the degree 2.

Indeed (contrary to what I originally wrote), it violates one important condition expected on degrees: With your definition, $p(x,y)=x^2$ and $q(x,y)=y^2$ both have the degree $2$, but the sum has degree $4$, which is larger than the degree of either of the polynomials.

It seems from your polynomials that the definition you had in mind is the highest degree of any monomial, which indeed is a reasonable definition of degree, but is different from your definition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue.  Does the second attempt look more reasonable?

Comment: @hchar: Yes, your second attempt is reasonable.